# How can I convert a time to hh:mm:ss format in Perl?

Tags: perl, posix, strftime

We need to convert the time column which is in number format to standard time format ie hh:mm:ss in perl.

Example:

1. If the time value is `1500`, the converted value should be `00:15:00`.
2. If the time value is `11500`, the converted value should be `01:15:00`.

I have tried this:

```
use POSIX qw(strftime); 
printf( strftime("%H:%M:%S",localtime(1500)));
```

But the output is `00:25:00` and I need the output to be `00:15:00`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I have tried this                                                                                        use POSIX qw(strftime);
printf( strftime("%H:%M:%S",localtime(1500)));     But output is 00:25:00, I need output to be 00:15:00

Comment: I have added your code to the question. You can also do that yourself by clicking [edit]. The reason that doesn't work is that `localtime` takes epoch seconds and converts them to a date and time representation. But you do not have seconds. You just have a badly formatted timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

To also convert from 24-hour to 12-hour time, it is probably best to use the `Time::Piece` module to convert from `%H%M%S` to `%I:%M:%S%p`. `sprintf` is still necessary as an initial step to pad the string with zeroes to six digits

This example program formats and prints time values each hour from 5900 to 235900

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

say format_time(1500);
say format_time(11500);
say '';

for my $time (0 .. 23) {
    $time = $time * 10000 + 5900;
    say format_time($time);
}

sub format_time {
    my ($time) = @_;
    $time = Time::Piece->strptime(sprintf('%06d', $time), '%H%M%S');
    lc $time->strftime('%I:%M:%S%p');
}
```

#### output

```
12:15:00am
01:15:00am

12:59:00am
01:59:00am
02:59:00am
03:59:00am
04:59:00am
05:59:00am
06:59:00am
07:59:00am
08:59:00am
09:59:00am
10:59:00am
11:59:00am
12:59:00pm
01:59:00pm
02:59:00pm
03:59:00pm
04:59:00pm
05:59:00pm
06:59:00pm
07:59:00pm
08:59:00pm
09:59:00pm
10:59:00pm
11:59:00pm
```

---

#### Original solution

In this solution, `sprintf('%06d', $time)` is used to pad the string to six digits using zeroes, and `/../g` splits the result into (three) chunks of two characters. The `join ':'` reassembles those chunks with colons in between to achieve the desired pattern

```
my $time = 1500;

my $converted = join ':', sprintf('%06d', $time) =~ /../g;

print $converted, "\n";
```

#### output

```
00:15:00
```

Comment: Since I'm seeing this in the Low Quality Posts Review section I'll leave a note here: Please add some explanation. :)

Comment: Of course this will work but will OP ever be able to understand it? Teach a man to fish and all that

Comment: I've added a new solution to allow for conversion from 24-hour to 12-hour times

Answer (score 4):

You first need to get the number to six digits by adding left zero padding. After that, you need to insert colons `:` after every two digits. The easiest way to do that is using [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) and a regular expression.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $date = '11500';
my $formatted = sprintf '%06d', $date;
$formatted =~ s/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/$1:$2:$3/;

say $formatted;
```

**Output**

```
01:15:00
00:15:00 (for 1150)
```

Note it will break for strings with length larger than six.

Comment: Yup thanks this working but next thing is number is 24 hour format that I need to convert to 12 hour format. ie if its 130000 then it should be 01:00:00

Comment: Please create a new question for that and try yourselves first

Comment: Here can we use sprintf and regular expression together? I mean in printf only I need to do padding and regular expression to insert colons : after every two disgits

Comment: Do you mean save a line? You can, if your perl is new enough to have the `/r` modifier. `my $formatted = sprintf('%06d', $date) =~ s/.../.../r;` You need Perl 5.14 for that. http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Regular-Expressions

Answer (score -2):

I found this code, please try

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime();

printf("Time Format - HH:MM:SS\n");
printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $hour, $min, $sec);
```

Our Put : 
Time Format - HH:MM:SS
06:58:52

Comment: That does not answer the question. OP wants to know how to convert a time string into a readable representation, not display the current time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but this is also not working when I put value as localtime(1500) still am getting output as 00:25:00, expected output is 00:15:00

Comment: http://perlmaven.com/simple-timestamp-generation-using-posix-strftime use this tutorial. u can get an idea,

Comment: He's not generating a timestamp. He's converting the timestamp from one format to another.